# What is the scope of variables in gyp?

Tags: chromium, gyp

The [gyp documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypUserDocumentation) documents the `'variables'` section like this:

> 'variables': Definitions of variables that can be interpolated and
>   used in various other parts of **the file**.

(emphasis mine).
This seems to exclude using the variables in included gyp files, and also exclude the possibility of including other gyp files that set variables.

Is this correct?  What is the scope of these variables, and how do you set variables globally?
I see that in Chromium, the `build/common.gypi` is setting lots of variables, but Chromium also is using a magic `gyp_chromium` script that is different from plain `gyp`.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of variables is GYP is very much alike with the scope of local variables in C++. Let's say you define a variable in a `variables` dictionary `FOO`. The scope of variables defined in `FOO` is the dictionary `BAR` which is parent of `FOO`. You can use those variables anywhere inside `BAR` and nowhere outside of it.

> how do you set variables globally?

Knowing the described rules it's very easy. Add a `variables` dictionary to the top-level dictionary of your gyp script and define some variables in it. They will be available anywhere<sup>1</sup> in this script.

> This seems to exclude using the variables in included gyp files, and
>   also exclude the possibility of including other `gyp` files that set
>   variables.

This is not true. Let's say you include `include.gypi` into `generator.gyp` script. If `include.gypi` has `variables` section in it's top-level dictionary, those variables would be accessible anywhere in the `generator.gyp`. Obviously variables defined not in the top-level dictionary would not be accessible.

<sup>1</sup> Keep in mind that `includes` are parsed before the variables expansion. Thus you can not use variables in includes paths.